# If I rename an index.html to index.php, the CSS style disappears

Tags: php, html, css, templates

Yesterday I discovered a website called Too Plate:

https://www.tooplate.com/about

It has free HTML templates, and all they are very beautiful.
I had the idea to turn the theme that I chose to PHP, so, I just renamed the file index.html to: index.php
But, when I open it using a brwser, all the style is gone... As if the template could not find the CSS file... But I just renamed the file, I did'nt change anything inside the code (I only added the "" tags a the beginning...)
This is the template:

https://www.tooplate.com/view/2122-nano-folio

How can I fix this, please?

Comment: this helps you ... https://www.highervisibility.com/blog/converting-html-to-wordpress-step-by-step-tutorial/

Comment: I downloaded the template, changed it to index.php and started it from localhost, it works perfectly fine. Did you start it from your local server? And also I am not sure what you mean by adding "" tags in the beginning

Comment: Hi Mr. P.! Thank you for your comment. May God bless your week!

Comment: @Alexandre nice though your comment is, it would be more helpful if you actually answer Mr P's questions - they are relevant to your issue.

Answer (score 1):

Once you add the PHP extension it handles the file as a PHP script, which is a server-side language that's get executed on the server before loading the page, so to view ant PHP file you have to have a server running the PHP code, but HTML runs on any browser.

So what happened was that because you changed the extension the browser treated it as a PHP script and cant Execute the script because it's not a server.

Answer (score 0):

you must need to run the code in server eg: local servr xampp or wampp then only your php code work try this